# EditorFor for list view error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, ienumerable, mvc-editor-templates, editorfor

I have a class which contains a property as a list of another object

```
public class MyObject {
    public MyObject()
    {
        this.Items = new List<Item>
                                {
                                    new Item(),
                                    new Item()
                                };
    }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public double ItemSetting { get; set; }

    [CompareIf("ItemSetting", Operator.LessThanOrEqual, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(UiResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ItemMinError")]
    public double ItemMin { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to display the list in a template:

```
@model IEnumerable<Web.Models.Item>
@{
}
```

via:

```
@model Web.Models.MyObject
@{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Items)
}
```

but I'm getting an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Web.Models.MyObject', but this dictionary requires a model item of
>   type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Web.Models.Item]'.

I'm passing to the editor template a property which is a type of List so why does it get it as a single Item type?

In the Item template I need to display a title which tells the index of the item in the List. Eg.:

```
<h3>Item 1</h3>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemSetting })
```

and for next Item:

```
<h3>Item 2</h3>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemSetting })
```

(Remember I created 2 empty items in MyObject constructor)

so haw do I get the relevant index if I'm only displaying one item in the Item template?

Comment: I assume you mean its `public class TemperatureItem` based on the model you have shown in the view? And is your template named `Item.cshtml` and in the `/View/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder?

Comment: Note also, `EditorFor()` accepts `IEnumerable<T>` so you `EditorTemplate` should be `@model Web.Models.Item` (not `IEnumerable<Web.Models.Item>` - the method is smart enough to generate the html for each item in the collection based on the html in the template

Comment: What are you passing to your view, is it `MyObject` or a List of `Item`?

Comment: How are you passing the model from one view to another?

Comment: @Coulton sorry I made a mistake in my question code, fixed now - I have MyObject view which displays editorfor List of Item so calls Item template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the value of your model is `null` (therefore `model.Items` is `null`) so by default, it passes the main model to the template. You need to ensure you pass an instance of you model to the view in the GET method.

However your method in the main view should be

```
@model Web.Models.Item
```

not `@model IEnumerable<Web.Models.Item>`. The method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and is smart enough to generate the html for each item in the collection based on the html in the template

Comment: How can you know this, when the OP hasn't supplied the controller code showing us exactly what he's passing to the view?

Comment: Because that's the exact message generated when the model is not passed to the view :)

Comment: @Coulton Ok, I got it and it works, thanks. The only problem I have now is that in Item template I need to display an index of the Item, so if I have created a List<Item> of 2 empty items I want to display in the editor a title like Item 1 or Item 2 depending on which item on the list it is, I have updated my question to reflect it.

Comment: @user1611620, You cant do that using an `EditorTemplate` (the method has no knowledge of which index in the collection the item is). To acheive that you will need to use a `for` loop in the main view - e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++) { <h3>Item @(i + 1)</h3> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].ItemSetting) }`

Comment: @Stephen I was doing exactly this initially (instead of using editor template) but the Item model has custom validation on it's properties and the validation was validating both items of List<Item> at once :( because it did not recognise each Item and its properties as different objects. I added Item class to my question

Comment: @user1611620, That should not be happening. I suggest you ask a new question with the relevant code, including your custom validation) to see what the issue might be.

Comment: @Stephen true, I was doing `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)` previously instead of `for (int i = 0; i < Model.Compartments.Count; i++)`. It works well now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have that error is because your controller and view are not passing the same type of object. probably your view is passing @model **Web.Models.Items** and what u need to pass to display a list of "items" is **@model Enumerable**